# how would you show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} 2\pi f(x_i *)(\sqrt{1+f'(x_i*)^2}-1) (x_i-x_{i-1})$ does not necessarily equal 0

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

how would you rigorously show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{i=n} 2\pi f(x_i *)(\sqrt{1+f'(x_i*)^2}-1) (x_i-x_{i-1})$ does not necessarily equal 0

Comment: Try an example and show that it's not zero for this example. Something simple like $f(x) = x$ should work.

Comment: What is the value of $x_i$?

Comment: $(x_i)$ is the value of x at the ith sub-interval

Answer (score 1):

That is a limit of a Riemann sum which defines the surface area of a solid of revolution.

$f(x) $ is positive and the radical is positive so the integral will not be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Are the $x_i$ in order, i.e. $x_i<x_{i+1}$? If so, you can let $(x_i-x_{i-1})=C$ where $C$=minimum($x_i-x_{i-1})$ for the correct $i$.

The radical is always greater than 1 because the square root function has a positive derivative everywhere on its domain, so the radical must always be greater than one if the argument is greater than one. The square of the derivative of f is always positive since f is a real function. So the middle term with the radical is always positive.

If f is always positive, then every individual term of the sum is positive so the sum of the series with C replacing the $x_i-x_{i-1}$ is positive. This new series is designed to be less than the original series, so the original series must be greater than that, and thus also positive.

Comment: Yes $x_{i}<x_{I+1}$ anyhow, thanks for your help